# Unable to login when using the try feature of Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, installation, boot

Everyone today for the first time I have download & burn the iso image of ubuntu 11.10 & when I tried to boot it. It went succussfuly but when i selected try ubuntu without installation. It worked but it asked me for user name & password.
When ever I entered anything it says - Invalid password. Try again.
Please help me anyone ASAP.
Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue while trying to boot from USB.

I solved it by downloading the iso again, and burning to CD.

Seems to be a faulty image issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try *ubuntu* with empty password. If that doesn't work, you will have to modify the CD image.

Comment: modify cd ! How?